# Is there a way to edit only part of a file?

Tags: folding

Unlike many people who are looking for this, or a similar sort of feature, it's not actually the file *size* I care about, I just find myself needing to deal with a very specific section of a file - maybe a couple hundred lines or less, so typically more than what fits on a screen at a reasonable font size.

One thought that I considered is creating a couple of marks, yanking that section, editing in a new split or tab, and then putting the edited text back.

That's kind of a hack, though, and doesn't make it so I can easily just save the text and run a command.

Manual folding could work for me, if I could make it so searches skip over the folds and they never open without a `zO` or something.

Is there any kind of way to edit a partial file in vim like that, or would I have to resort to some sweet hacks?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could try the terrific [NarrwRgn plugin](https://github.com/chrisbra/NrrwRgn) by our very own [Christian Brabandt](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/71/christian-brabandt), which has always worked very well for me.

Just select the lines you're interested in in visual mode, and then type `:NR` to open a new buffer containing just that area. Any changes you `:write` in the new buffer will appear instantly in the original, and you can simply close it when you're done: `:q`.

Comment: Hot dang that's fantastic. Pretty much exactly what I wanted!

Comment: Thansk for mentioning my plugin ;)

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt It's a great plugin!